# how to get image from photo library by giving a image name in iOS 7

Tags: ios7

i want to get image from photo library in iPhone simulator by simply giving image name or full path. but i cant get idea to do that. please get me out from here.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you need to get your image from photo library without opening library? or you need to get image from photo library by picking an image photo library will get opened?

Comment: if you would like to open image from photo library you have to use uiimagepicker controller and implement its delegates methods.

Comment: to access photo library you have to use following way.          NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); NSString *libPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access library directory you need to used **NSLibraryDirectory** instead of **NSDocumentDirectory** and then use following code. I think it might be useful to you.

```
NSString* fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",patientlastName];
NSArray *arrayPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *path = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* pdfFileName = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
UIImage *image1=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pdfFileName];
imageView.image=image1;
```

If you would like to open photo library and get image from there, you have to use UIImagePickerController and implements its delegate methods like below.

above the @implementation of your class in .m file, use folllowing code

```
#pragma mark - NON Rotation
@interface NonRotatingUIImagePickerController : UIImagePickerController

@end

@implementation NonRotatingUIImagePickerController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

@end
```

then in implementation of your class .m file use below code.

```
-(void)openPhotoLibrary {

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
                         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
                    {
                        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
                        [[NonRotatingUIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                        imagePicker.delegate = self;
                        imagePicker.sourceType =
                        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
                        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                  (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                                                  nil];
                        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    }
}
```

**UIImagePickerController Delegates**

```
#pragma mark - ImagePicker Controller Delegate
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
 NSString *mediaType = [info
                           objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
UIImage *image = [info
                          objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        imageView.image = image;
}
}

-(void)image:(UIImage *)image
finishedSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
 contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    if (error) {
//Right some error related code...
}
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I think this would be helpful to you.